# Listview display tick icon when open

Tags: java, android

I assume that I have activity A, activity B, and activity C. in activity A there is a listview that displays the name of activity B and C. how do I display the tick icon on the listview in activity A when I finish opening activity B or activity C like the example image below.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlreA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Add an `ImageView` to the right side of your `ListView` item layout and set it to be visible just after calling `startActivity()`. Or, if this is making the checkmarks visible too soon, you can use `startActivityForResult()`, which will allow you to set the `ImageView`'s visibility only upon returning to `Activity` A. If your `ListView` isn't using custom item layouts, you'll need to [learn how to do that](https://javapapers.com/android/android-listview-custom-layout-tutorial/).